# Mysql ID Duplication issue in Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysqlbinlog, multi-master-replication

I tried implementing MySQL replication with 3 systems.

In my setup I have pairs as follows

```
                (Master  ,Slave   )
                (System_1,System_2)
                (System_1,System_3)

                (System_2,System_1)
                (System_2,System_3)

                (System_3,System_1)
                (System_3,System_2)
```

So, every system is master and slave of every other system in this setup.

Every system is having local db as well.

Now in simple case everything is working fine. But in testing i faces an issue which is...

Say at some moment System_3 goes out of connectivity not at this moment all 3 system having some entries till id=3 (primary key and unique).

System_1

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |
| 3 | pqr |

System_2

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |
| 3 | pqr |

System_3

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |
| 3 | pqr |

Now say when System_3 is offline it made some entry that will be going with id 4 in it table locally, in the mean time other two systems namely System_1, System_2 which are online, made some entry that will also go with id 4 in their respective table with replication.

Now say System_3 came online and it will read bin log file of other system and try to insert changes made at other system for replication at id 4. But boom System_3 already have value at id 4. Here replication got stop.

My question is how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in master-master replication scenarios. One way to deal with it is to give every system a [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) of the number of systems.

In combination with `auto_increment_offset` you can avoid duplicate keys.

This way you can make sure that system_1 only gives ids `3, 6, 9, ...` and system_2 `2, 5, 8, ...` and system_3 `1, 4, 7, ...`

Comment: You are right but in that case what if i have to update from System_1 to all other systems using id?
I mean i can not update like below

update tablename set columnName = 'Some Value' where id = 3;

Comment: sure, why not? this just changes how each MySQL server chooses the next Auto Increment ID in case it has to insert a row.